# Save and load date localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have to save a date to localStorage and when the page is refreshed I want to calculate how much time has passed since then.

Now, here's the problem: localStorage saves the date as a string so after it is saved in localStorage trying to calculate the difference between those two dates returns NaN.

Try this in your javascript console:

```
var a = new Date();
var b = new Date();
console.log(b - a); //this works
localStorage.a = a;
localStorage.b = b;
console.log(localStorage.b - localStorage.a); //this doesn't work
```

I also tried `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` trying to keep the date object intact, but that doesn't work either.

My guess is that I have to parse the date in the localStorage. If there is not a better method, how can I do that?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/AuhtS/

**Code:**

```
var a = new Date();
var b = new Date();
console.log(b - a); //this works
localStorage.a = a;
localStorage.b = b;
a = Date.parse(localStorage.a); // parse to date object
b = Date.parse(localStorage.b);
console.log(b - a); // now, this will work
```

**Reason**

Everything is stored as a **string** in `localStorage`.

So when you do `localStorage.b - localStorage.a`, what you're attempting is trying to subtract one string from another. Which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: I know. How does this answer my question?

Comment: One sec, will help you with the parsing logic.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` parses valid JSON strings into JavaScript objects. It does not parse Date formats. For parsing date formats, you can use `date = Date.parse(string)` as you can see in the demo.

Comment: keep in mind a = Date.parse(localStorage.a) returns the time in milliseconds. if you want to return it to a date object, do a = new Date(localStorage.a); then use a.getTime() if you need the milliseconds

Comment: On mobile iOS this still is a support problem, needs polyfill

Answer (score 9):

To store a date in localStorage, simply do

```
localStorage['key'] = ''+myDate.getTime();
```

And to restore it :

```
var myDate = new Date(parseInt(localStorage['key'], 10));
```

(you might also want to test it's defined before)

It also works with duration (a date minus another one) : Simply use the value as long (millisecondes) and convert to and from a string.

Note that JSON doesn't include a standardized date format. Don't use JSON for dates.

Comment: as getTime returns a number, you should really convert it to a string when storing it:  myDate.getTime().toString()

Comment: @AndyLorenz If you look closely, my answer already includes a conversion to string (and it's not really necessary as it would be done anyway, it's just for clarity of the storage).

Comment: IMHO you should always be explicit with types where you can, and the toString function is in the language for this very purpose.  But yes your approach does work - just by an implicit coercion into a string. On the flip-side, I see you use parseInt to convert the string back to a number, as opposed to say localStorage['key']-0 !

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this:

```
var d1 = new Date();
localStorage.setItem("key", d1.getTime());
var d2 = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem[key]));
```

all that is missing is proper null validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go for:

```
var date1 = <date1>
var date2 = <date2>
localStorage.setItem('date1', date1.toString())
localStorage.setItem('date2', date2.toString())

var date1 = new Date(localStorage.getItem('date1'))
var date2 = new Date(localStorage.getItem('date2'))
var diff = date1 - date2
```

Comment: Date.parse will also work .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need it in `Date` type. Therefore, here it is:

```
var a = new Date();
localStorage.a = a;
var c = new Date(localStorage.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date Comparison from Local Storage : 
    var date1 = <date1>
    var date2 = <date2>
    localStorage.setItem('date1', date1.toString())
    localStorage.setItem('date2', date2.toString())
    
    var date1 = Date.parse(localStorage.getItem('date1'))
    var date2 = Date.parse(localStorage.getItem('date2'))
    var diff = date1 - date2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
localStorage.setItem("date", new Date().toString());
```

you can directly add like this

Answer (score -3):

I believe that localStorage only takes timestamps. Correct me if I am wrong. I suggest you use the moment library instead of the JS built in Date library.
moment is way easier to use and has some handy builtin functions.
One is toString() which allows you to parse the data as a string.
an example is:

```
// create a moment (the current time)
const now = moment()
// convert it to a timestamp to store it in localStorage
now.valueOf()
// get the data back in string format
now.toString()
```

Moment also has the useful .fromNow() method, which allow you to get the time difference from the date was created to the moment it was edited.
I hope this help. read the docs for moment for more info here: https://momentjs.com/docs/