# How to subtract a date via Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, difference

I have an add date and I need to know how many days ago this record was added, so today - adddate. This is in mm/dd/yyyy format (10/16/2014) and I wanted to know if there is an easy way to get the difference without adding a new plugin. Thanks!

```
var today = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date());
var adddate = $('#adddate').val();

alert(today - adddate);
```

Comment: Sounds similar to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661293/save-and-load-date-localstorage Meaning that you have to `parseDate` before being able to subtract it.

Comment: Just convert both dates to milliseconds and do the subtraction manually. Convert back to number of days after subtraction.

Comment: How do I convert to milliseconds and convert back?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both values are inside inputs, this works.

```
var d1 = $('#adddate').datepicker('getDate');
var d2 = $('#today').datepicker('getDate');
var diff = 0;

    if (d1 && d2) {
        diff = Math.floor((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 86400000); // ms per day
    }

    alert(diff)
```