# How to parse localStorage Item to date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, local-storage

I am trying to getItem from localStorage and try to parse it into a date variable.

```
  var date= new Date();
  //setting item
  localStorage.setItem('dateIs', date);

  //retrieving item from local storage
  var newDate= new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('dateIs'));
  alert(newDate);
```

**OR**

```
   //retrieving item from local storage
  var newDate= new Date(localStorage.getItem('dateIs');
  alert(newDate);
```

It shows 'Invalid Date' in the alert both.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661293/save-and-load-date-localstorage

Comment: second one (minus the typo) works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script had a few flaws

```
   var date= new Date();
  //setting item
  localStorage.setItem('dateIs', date);

  //retrieving item from local storage
  var newDate = new Date(localStorage.getItem('dateIs'));
  alert(newDate);
```

it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/ax1hyLn2/1/

Comment: @RibelynPunk forgot a ) after setting the newdate

Comment: @sjoreddewit i saw your comment now i have solved it, please vote my question back then i will rank your question up.. need 15 minimum...worked fine... thanx...