# Display an an element(by ID) only per web session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have this widget element that needs to show up per web session and not for each page and after some research i realized i need to set cookies for this element.

What can you suggest me on this?

UPDATE >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>:

I had some help from the answers below and so far this is what we came up with and even though the new script adds a storage session, it doesn't actually replace the `display:block` rule with `none`.

```js
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("elementViewed") === "true") {
  let element = document.getElementById('block-16');
  element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 20vh;
}

#block-16 {
  position: fixed!important;
  width: auto;
  right: 100px;
  top: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

aside {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<aside id="block-16" class="footer_widgets widget_block col-xs-12 col-md-3">
  <p>test</p>
  <!-- A slider shortcode comes here and this slider has its own animation like fadeIn and FadeOut in 10 seconds thats why it doesnt need an extra animation script or Css rule -->
```

Comment: You could use the official MDN documentation on [How to retrieve a cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie#example_5_check_a_cookie_existence) and how to set it. It is sufficient to do everything on the client side. - Even easier would be setting a either a localStorage or sessionStorage variable like `visitedSite: a date string` and see if it is set and with which value.

Comment: For the second idea, have a look here: [Save and load date localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661293/save-and-load-date-localstorage)

Comment: As you can see, the code works. - https://jsfiddle.net/640fe7g3/
Do you get an error in your console? Do you close the <aside> tag properly?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) property, which is scoped to the current browser session.

You would set a value in `sessionStorage` after the first view of the element, or on click if it has a close button.

Setting the value would look something like:

```js
window.sessionStorage.setItem("elementViewed", "true");
// true is a string, as sessionStorage key and value are strings
```

Then you'd check for that value on page load:

```js
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem("elementViewed") === "true") {
    let element = document.getElementById('block-16');
    element.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: This actually registers the cookie to session storage as i can see from Cookies in use part of the browser but it doesn't apply the  `element.style.display = 'none';` code for some reason and you can still see the element everywhere other than added cookie.

Comment: @SelcukxD check in browser developer tools if the inline styling is applied and check for other CSS rules which may overwrite it. _(eg. display: block !important)_  You can also console.log(element) to see if the element is found or console.log((window.sessionStorage.getItem("elementViewed") === "true")) to see if the condition returns true

Comment: @Uwe so basically i checked the if there is an overruling situation and i can confirm there isn't. On the other hand i tried the commands and the first one returned with the name of the element and for the second command you mentioned > `console.log((window.sessionStorage.getItem("elementViewed") === "true"))`  
 returns false even though there is an already extra registered cookie that comes from the script.

Comment: @SelcukxD you have to use the provided `window.sessionStorage.setItem("elementViewed", "true");` - which does not set a cookie but a value in the sessionStorage. Only then the second Part can work. I just tested the snippets and they work. Please edit your question with your most up-to-date code.

Comment: @Uwe yes you are right. I think i wanted to say session storage as well but i thought it was a cookie so my bad. As you mentioned it also sets that value for me but just doesn't apply the CSS rule even tho i checked that there is no overruling code.

Comment: When `console.log((window.sessionStorage.getItem("elementViewed") === "true"))` returns `false` then the code is not executed. You should try to figure out, why it does evaluate as false, when you say it is set, then is should evaluate to true, when you check it.  --- Edit you question an put all your new code into the question and remove the previous codes.